# Strange quotes appearing during TCP connection, QT

Tags: c++, string, qt, tcp, quotes

I'm sending strings over TCP in my client/server app. On client side, getting strings looks like:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_login_clicked()
{
    QByteArray login = (ui->login_input->text()).toUtf8();
    QByteArray password = (ui->password_input->text()).toUtf8();
    connection->ConnectAndSendData(login, password);
}

void TcpConnect::ConnectAndSendData(const QByteArray login, const QByteArray password)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    int port = 1234;
    socket->connectToHost("localhost", port);

    if(socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug() << "connected to s. localhost at port " << port;
        //socket->flush();
        socket->write(MESSAGE_WANTLOGIN);
        qDebug() << login<< "\n";

        socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        QByteArray response = socket->readAll();
        qDebug() << "got response " << response;
        if(response == MESSAGE_LOGINRQ)
        {
            socket->write(login);
            qDebug() << "i wrote " << login;
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "not LOGINRQ";

        socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        response = socket->readAll();
        qDebug() << "got response " << response;
        if(response == MESSAGE_PASSRQ)
        {
            socket->write(password);
            qDebug() << "i wrote " << password;
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "not PASSRQ" << response;

        socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        response = socket->readAll();
        qDebug() << "got username: " << response;
        QByteArray username = response;
        socket->flush();
        socket->close();
    }
    else
    {
        emit changeInfoLabel(QString("Serwer nie odpowiada. Sprawdz swoje polaczenie sieciowe."));
        qDebug() << "unable to connect to server";
    }
}
```

server who receiving messages look like:

```
void Thread::readyRead()
{
    socket->flush();
    QByteArray request, login, password;
    request = socket->readAll();

    qDebug() << "data received: " << request;
    if(request == MESSAGE_WANTLOGIN)
    {
        socket->write(MESSAGE_LOGINRQ);
        qDebug() << "Login request: " << MESSAGE_LOGINRQ;
        qDebug() << "\"";
        socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        login = socket->readAll();
        qDebug() << "Login readed: " << login;
        socket->write(MESSAGE_PASSRQ);
        qDebug() << "password request: " << MESSAGE_PASSRQ;
        socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);
        password = socket->readAll();
        qDebug() << "password readed: " << password;

        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

            db.setHostName("localhost");
            db.setDatabaseName("gamebase");
            db.setUserName("root");
            db.setPassword("");

            if(!db.open())
                qDebug() << "cant connect to database";
            else
            {
                QStringList tables = db.tables();
                for(int i=0;i<tables.size();i++)
                    qDebug() << tables.at(i);

                QSqlQuery pobieranie;
                QByteArray query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login=\""+login+"\" AND password=\""+password+"\"";
                qDebug() << "zapytanie: " << query;
                qDebug() <<  " natomiast login " << login << " haslo " << password;
                if(!pobieranie.exec(query))
                {
                    qDebug() << "No records";
                } else
                {
                    socket->write(pobieranie.value("username").toString().toUtf8());
                }

                db.close();
            }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "error not messageloginrq";
    }
}
```

and everything works generally fine, but it seems, that somewhere in the code or somewhere in TCP stream are added quotes to sending strings, so sent data instead of: login and password is: "login" and "password". Because of this query "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login=\""+login+"\" AND password=\""+password+"\""; is completely messed up and cant be executed properly. Why this code behave like this?

Comment: You are aware that `qDebug` will automatically add double quotes around a `QString` or `QByteArray`?  Is that what's causing the confusion?

Comment: yes i know, so why is select query messed up? output of qDebug() << "zapytanie: " << query: is SELECT * FROM user WHERE login=\"LOGIN\" AND password=\"PASSWORD\" instead of SELECT * FROM user WHERE login="LOGIN" AND password="PASSWORD"

Comment: Can you clarify... in your question you say `login=\""+login+"\"` but your comment says `login=\"LOGIN\"` -- the quotes are different in those two cases.  What I would *expect* to see from `qDebug` in that case would be something more like `login="\"login\""`.  Sorry if I appear pedantic but the difference is significant as your `query` is constructed with explicit double quotes around both the `login` and `password` values.

Comment: OK somehow query is executed as indeed, but im still a bit confused about this output from qDebug().

Comment: You're facing expected behavior from `qDebug()`. Feel free to try passing objects of various types to `qDebug()` and see how it behaves. Then you'll understand what happened here.